# Two dimensional array address and corresponding pointer to its 1st element

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In terms of one dimensional array, its array name is also the address of the first element. So it is fine to assign it to a pointer, like below:

```
char data[5];
char* p_data=data;
```

So I think it should be the same with two dimensional array. The array name should be the address of the first element's address. So, I'd like to do something like this:

```
char data[5][5];
char** pp_data=data;
```

Then I get a warning saying the pointer type `char**` is incompatible with `char[ ][ ]`.

Why does this happen? Do I comprehend the pointer and array concept wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that an array is often referred to by a pointer to its first element.  But when you have the "two dimensional" array

```
char data[5][5];
```

what you actually have is an *array of arrays*.  The first element of the array `data` is an array of 5 characters.  So this code would work:

```
char (*pa_data)[5] = data;
```

Here `pa_data` is a *pointer to array*.  The compiler won't complain about it, but it may or may not actually be useful to you.

It's true that a pointer-to-pointer like your `char **pp_data` can be made to act like a two-dimensional array, but you have to do some memory allocation for it to work.  It turns out that in the array-of-arrays `char data[5][5]` there's no pointer-to-`char` for `pp_data` to be a pointer to.  (In particular, you could **not** say something like `pp_data = &data[0][0]`.)

See also [this question](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Two dimensional array is actually an *array of arrays*. It means the first element of that array is an array. Therefore a two dimensional array will be converted to pointer to an array (its first element).

In

```
char data[5][5];
```

when used in expression, wit some exception, `data` will be converted to pointer to its first element `data[0]`.`data[0]` is an array of `char`. Therefore the type of `data` will become *pointer to an array of 5 `char`*, i.e. `char (*)[5]`.

`char **` and `char (*)[5]` are of different type, i.e. incompatible type.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks a lot!~